# How to restrict manageable entities in Active Admin?

Tags: activeadmin

I would like to restrict the list of manageable model entities in Active Admin based on an attribute of the current_user and the model entity.

e.g: A User (with admin rights) have a team_id == 2 and should only be able to manage 
Tasks with a team_id == 2

Edit: I'm trying to use scopes but I don't know how to scope using this condition:

```
user.team_id == task.team_id
```

Is that possible with Active Admin?

Thanks for your time.(This is my first post, tell me if I can improve my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to use scopes:

```
scope_to :current_user
```

And add to User model:

```
has_many :tasks, through: :team
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably trying to define different levels of access and authorization. You should look into the CanCan gem: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

ActiveAdmin explains how to implement it here: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using_the_cancan_adapter

Then in your case you could define an ability.rb like:

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
        user ||= User.new
        case user.team_id
            when 1
                can :manage, Post
            when 2
                can :manage, Post
                can :manage, Task
            when 3
                can :manage, :all
        end
        can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Dashboard"
    end
end
```

I would suggest defining a `role` attribute instead of using `team_id`, but that's just being picky with semantic :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry I was too vague, there are not different levels of access, I'm trying to scope everything with the condition user.team_id == task.team_id